# Build Failure: A failure occured while executing com.android.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, augmented-reality

When I try to build the Augmented Reality Based Android Application in unity, some point of time it stuck in the IPostGenerateGradleAndroidProject callbacks phase:[image]

After Some time I am getting the following error:
[image]

Can someone help me to fix this error...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this information will be useful, but after deleting Easy Mobile plugin from my android project error disappeared and i buil project successfully. And i wanted to read about Easy mobile in asset store, then found out that plugin deleted from there because it was deprecated